# How can I embed linux virtual machines in a website or a webapp?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, container, web, virtual-consoles

I am planning to start a project to build a webapp, and I had an idea that I have seen in many places.

I have seen some websites where they have a linux virtual machine and a bash terminal is embedded in the webpage and users can enter commands and interact with it and they have access to a separate machine or resources.

I was wondering how I could do that in my webapp.

---

I am new to stackexchange and posted this question in stackoverflow and was told to move it here.

Edit 1:
There is one website I remember that has something like it. Its immersivelabs.com. They have "labs" and they have a terminal on the side where you type commands and stuff and you are tested based on that

Comment: Have you looked into the websites you are referring to? You can learn from them. I am pretty sure what you saw were sessions of https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox or https://novnc.com/info.html. A virtual machine which actually runs in the browser is possible as shown by https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdosbox/ for example. However, this is only DOS. Virtualizing a Linux machine in the Browser is unwieldy.

Comment: You can also check how https://guacamole.apache.org/ is working.

Comment: A web-based terminal emulator, and containers?

Comment: Perhaps you're talking about JSLinux, which is a bit different than the above suggestions since it run it locally in your browser? https://bellard.org/jslinux/

Comment: So there is one website I remember that has something like it. Its immersivelabs.com.  They have "labs" and they have a terminal on the side where you type commands and stuff and you are tested based on that

Comment: Oh by the way, on stack overflow I was told to move this post here which is why I am here. I do learn from all the websites I come across tho xD